# Chrome extension (v35) + Group policy (GPO) + regedit not work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, regedit, gpo

I've already read all same questions (stackoverflow and all threads/bugs/reports on google forums) but don't find the answer.

I made a simple chrome extension. Windows XP and Windows 8 (64bit). Chrome v35+.

I use GPO (gpedit.msc) - it doesn't work (nothing changes at chrome://policy). (maybe if I understand how it works i will solve my problem?)
Then I use regedit tools (or regedit file like example.reg) and set something like

```
 **32bit**

 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\EXTENSION_ID]
 "path"="C:/extension/SampleExtension.crx"
 "version"="1.0.0"

 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist]
 "1"="EXTENSION_ID;file:///C:/extension/update.xml"

 **64bit**

 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\EXTENSION_ID]
 "path"="C:/extension/SampleExtension.crx"
 "version"="1.0.0"

 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallForcelist]
 "1"="EXTENSION_ID;file:///C:/extension/update.xml"
```

and after this my extension is appear in chrome://extensions (by the way with GoogleDocs which was already turned on =)
but my extension was disabled (turned off) and near it was inscription: "Installed by a third party".

I want (and can't) do some things to get inscription like "Installed by enterprise policy". And I want it to be initially turn on.

Anybody can help?

PS:
ADM templates http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates

Policy List http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3

By the way, in earlier chrome versions I think it solved by setting policy 'InstantEnabled' (now it is deprecated).

Comment: Is your machine part of a domain?

Comment: I've already read something about it but I don't know what is it?

Comment: Oo, i see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/connect-computer-domain#1TC=windows-7 but what differ from workgroup and what values "domain" can get?

Comment: And why windows must be connected to a domain (any domain?)? Is it a policy of chrome extensions? but why..

Comment: I'm not sure if its related to the same problem (blocked non-PlayStore extensions) but you may try some of the general solutions proposed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095006/enable-a-non-playstore-userscript-with-chrome-35-and-above

Answer (score 5):

Google has recently made many changes to extension handling. First they changed the ExtensionInstallForcelist policy so it only works for domain-joined systems. It no longer works for local policy.

Then they made another change in the past week to only allow extensions to run if they're present in the Chrome web store. This has angered a lot of extension developers and users.

The policy is outlined here: http://chrome.blogspot.com/2014/05/protecting-chrome-users-from-malicious.html.

The discussion (filled with lots anger about this change) is here: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/d35tIyH8dVM/J2CJ4Gop94sJ

Comment: The second link is a dead link :/

Comment: That same link worked this morning but took a while to render. I just updated with a better link.

Comment: This helped me a great deal. I spent the better part of an afternoon troubleshooting the force installation until I came across your answer which reminded me about the computer NEEDING to be domain-joined. Many thanks!